# I18n in service layer

Tags: spring, service, struts2, domain-driven-design

My project use struts2 and spring, I have some service method to deal with business logic.
e.g

```
public void aMethod(){
    if(!validate()) return;
    process();
}

private boolean validate() {
    return validateA()&&validateB()&&validateB();
}
```

But when I call in action (Controller) layer, I found that no error message show in page.
So I change my method to blow:

```
public String validate() {
    if (!validateA()) {
        return "error.msg.A";
    } else if (!validateB())  {
        return "error.msg.B";
    }
    return  null;
}
```

Action layer call validate method directly and get the error message to process i18n related work.

My question is that: 
Any best practices for i18n in service layer?
My validate method is very strange in service layer after my change. Any good way to show i18n error message and also keep service layer clear?

Comment: You can throw custom exceptions from the service layer that you can handle by your controller, then you can provide custom messages to the view layer which is i18n aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is to have custom exceptions that have a **key** and **message** attributes.
The key is the i18n key for that error, and the message is a default message.

So in the service:

```
try{
  some code
}
  catch(SomeException e){
  handleAppropriatly;
  throw new MyCustomException("error.foo","Some default message",e);
}
```

The action catches the message and adds it to the correct place appropriately (addActionError/addFieldError) using the key, allowing you to take advantage of any internationalisation you have.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I think this what I can do currently. But I don't like use exception to pass error message.:)